# weird scroll issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have an weird issue in IE8. I have a bunch of div's in an area. Each div has the same structure. Here is the basic structure.

```
<div class="brandImage">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <a><img/></a>
        <div><a href="/different/page.aspx"><span>See More</span></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each `brandImage` div has an on hover listener which will give the inner div a `display:block` reveling the image and allowing the user to click through.

All these "tiles" are contained in a div with a set height and is scroll-able using the [jquery.mCustomScrollbar](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/blob/master/js/uncompressed/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js) plugin.

It works with all the tiles above the fold, however, when a you start to scroll down below the fold, if you click on one of the tiles, on `mousedown` will cause the container to scroll up. If the container does not have to scroll very far or you release the mouse button fast enough to complete the click it will work.

My question is what could be causing the scroll up on the `mousedown` event?

Comment: Well, messing with default scrollbar behavior is _asking for trouble_. Apart from that: At least a live example please.

Comment: @CBroe yes it is. But the designer insisted.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin defaulted to scroll on focus. The function that was called on `focusin`. This was scrolling the container. Here is the code from the plugin.

```
/*scrolling on element focus (e.g. via TAB key)*/
        if($this.data("autoScrollOnFocus")){
            if(!$this.data("bindEvent_focusin")){
                mCustomScrollBox.bind("focusin",function(){
                    mCustomScrollBox.scrollTop(0).scrollLeft(0);
                    var focusedElem=$(document.activeElement);
                    if(focusedElem.is("input,textarea,select,button,a[tabindex],area,object")){
                        var mCSB_containerPos=mCSB_container.position().top,
                            focusedElemPos=focusedElem.position().top,
                            visibleLimit=mCustomScrollBox.height()-focusedElem.outerHeight();
                        if($this.data("horizontalScroll")){
                            mCSB_containerPos=mCSB_container.position().left;
                            focusedElemPos=focusedElem.position().left;
                            visibleLimit=mCustomScrollBox.width()-focusedElem.outerWidth();
                        }
                        if(mCSB_containerPos+focusedElemPos<0 || mCSB_containerPos+focusedElemPos>visibleLimit){
                            $this.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",focusedElemPos,{trigger:"internal"});
                        }
                    }
                });
                $this.data({"bindEvent_focusin":true});
            }
        }
```

When I initialize the plugin, I set `autoScrollOnFocus` to false and there was no issue.